# How can i enable bookmark bar of firefox browser using selenium

Tags: selenium, capybara

How can i enable bookmark bar of firefox browser using selenium webdriver. I need to enable it for cucumber ruby test cases.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have solve this issue myself
I have execute javascript that is i have run javascript code by selenium webdriver

```
page.driver.brower.execute_execript(javascript function here)
```

Comment: How exactly does this solve your problem? Does WebDriver allow you to run scripts with browser-level access to enable the toolbar via JS?

Comment: Actually, I have find the js of bookmark icon which is shown on bookmark bar. and run this js using page.driver.brower.execute_execript(javascript function here) and it is treat as click on bookmark icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-create a custom Firefox profile with the bookmark toolbar enabled and instantiate the WebDriver with said profile every time. This will also result in lower startup times, since WebDriver won't have to create a clean profile every time.

[Do it like this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Using_an_existing_profile):

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => "my-existing-profile")
```

Comment: This is not working. Please provide complete solutions
I have changed like that 
    profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new; 
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, :profile => profile)

Comment: @vijaychouhan You should just create a new profile manually in Firefox (and name it, say "Selenium-testing-bookmarks-enabled"), config everything the way you want, close the browser. And from now on, just use this profile for Selenium testing, so instead of `"my-existing-profile"` in the answer, you'd have `"Selenium-testing-bookmarks-enabled"`. This won't create a new profile every time, but will reuse the same one again and again.